# How to apply hot key in menubar / submenu using primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hotkeys

I would like apply for hot key on Menu Bar/ Sub Menu Bar Using Prime Faces.

When i applied Hot key (like ctrl+f) then menu would be appearing like this [image]

[image]

When i click in File Menu then its working fine but using the hot key its not appear.

So, Any buddy can tell me what i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

From theory you could use `<p:hotkey>` as shown in the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/hotkey.jsf).

However, you need to bind it to a client side widget action. So you need to find out which is the widgetVar of your menu and the javascript action method to open the menu.